# Range of $f(n) = n^2+1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Let $f(n)$ be the function from the set of positive integers to the set of integers such that $f(n) = n^2+1$. What is the range of this function?

Since the range is the set of images, I thought the range would be $\{2,5,10,\ldots\}$ but my book says the range is $\mathbb{N}$. How is it that?

Comment: How old is the book?

Comment: @Ed_4434 It is from Discrete Mathematics by Kenneth Rosen.

Comment: Alright, it depends on how the author defines range. Some people define range as the codomain of the function while others define it as the image. The set you wrote down is what I would call the image while $\Bbb N$ is the codomain of $f$.

Comment: @Ed_4434 The codomain is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Um... f(n) = m means n^2 + 1 = m s n^2 = m-1 so n = root (m -1) so range can only exist on numbers that are 1 more than perfect squares.  SO you are correct that the image is the set you describe.  Ed_4434 is probably correct that the author meant range = codomain.  But, IMO that's kind of dumb as f:N->N by definition so there is no point in the question.  (Also we could just as easily so f:N -> R so....)

Comment: @Puzzled417 Give me an $n$ such that $f(n) \leq 0$

Comment: Give me an n such that f(n) = 1  or f(n) = 27.  Puzzled417 has a point.  If range *doesn't* mean Image  why should it mean any other X so that Image $\subset$ X.  The codomain is *declared* by fiat to by $\mathbb Z$.  It could just as easily been declared but be $\mathbb N$ or $\mathbb Q$ or ...

Comment: @fleablood fair one!

Comment: Getting the right anwer on paper is not as important as knowing what you are talking about.  In this case the OP is correct in identifying the Image of the function.  So if s/he reads up how his/her text defines range and co-domain, s/he is in good shape no matter what the answer on paper actually is.

Answer (score 1):

*Range* may refer to either the image or the codomain. These are not always the same thing.

In the case above, the image is the set of squares-plus-one as you correctly worked out, while the codomain is all of the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ (which is a superset of the domain itself) as declared in the question you quote.

The later statement is inconsistent with the definition of the codomain given by the question, and it's safe to assume that it is wrong as written. Likely the intent was to write "... to the set of *positive* integers" - some authors synonymize the latter with the naturals $\mathbb{N}:=\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: The quoted exercise explicitly described $f$ as "function from the set of positive integers **to the set of integers**", so its codomain is $\mathbb Z$ by explicit specification.

Comment: You've updated your answer.  But now, the book says the answer is $\mathbb N$.  Perhaps we should just point out that 1) the OP is correct in identifying the image (output) of the function, 2) that $Image = \{n^2+1|n \in \mathbb N\} \subset \mathbb N \subset \mathbb Z \subset \mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$ and 3) the book in defining $f:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb Z$ but declaring "Range = $\mathbb N$" is being inconsistant.

Answer (score 1):

Something must be wrong either with the book you're quoting from, or with your quoting.

The word "range" can mean either the **codomain** of the function, or the set of values in the codomain that the function actually attains.

But the latter of these is $\{2,5,10,17,\ldots\}$, and the former is *explicitly specified* to be $\mathbb Z$:

> Let $f(n)$ be the function from the set of positive integers **to the set of integers** such that

There is no principled way to get the answer to come out as $\mathbb N$.

Either your book is simply wrong, or you're misquoting the exercise and it actually says "... to the set of *positive* integers ...".

Comment: That first value is also 2. I see you caught the others already ;)

Comment: I agree.  But lets give the OP some well deserved credit for knowing what's what.  S/he correctly identified what image means and what it would be, understands both concepts that range can be defined as codomain or image, correctly identified the codomain when the book failed to do so.  I'd so s/he is in good shape and what the book actually meant or said is not very important.

Comment: In case the exercise says “to the set of positive integers”, then the question would be much like “what color was Napoleon's white horse?”, assuming the correct answer is $\mathbb{N}$. I don't think the answer given by the book makes any sense.

Comment: Well, to give the book credit, the OP cited the question wrong.  The book says: f maps the set of integers to the set of integers.  So domain is Z.  Codomain is Z but image is a *subset* of $\mathbb N$.  The book got that part wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I' looked the book up:  http://www2.fiit.stuba.sk/~kvasnicka/Mathematics%20for%20Informatics/Rosen_Discrete_Mathematics_and_Its_Applications_7th_Edition.pdf

(1071 pages!!!!)

And I found the problem (Chapter 2. Question 8):

a)
Define the domain, codomain, and range of a function.
b)
Let
$f (n)$
be the function from **the set of integers** to **the
set of integers** such that
$f (n)=n^2+1$.

What are the
*domain*, *codomain*, and *range* of the function. (bolding mine)

Okay, I'd say in this case the domain is *not* $\mathbb N$ but $\mathbb Z$.

The codomain, by declaration is $\mathbb Z$ and the range is {$1,2,5,....n^2 + 1$} and it's clear in context that range means image... unless it's good enough to notice "$f(n) \ge 1$ so range is $\mathbb N$".  I .... don't like that for obvious reasons, but... I can see how an excercise might expect.

.....

Hold on a minute while I continue to read what the book says.

> **DEFINITION 2**
>   If
>   $f$
>   is a function from
>   $A$ to
>   $B$, we say that
>   $A$ is the
>   *domain*
>   of
>   $f $ and
>   $B$ is the
>   *codomain*
>   of
>   $f$.
>   If
>   $f(a)=
> b
> $, we say that
>   $b
> $ is the
>   *image*
>   of
>   $a$ and
>   $a$
>   is a
>   *preimage*
>   of
>   $b$. The
>   *range*, or
>   *image*,
>   of
>   $f$ is the set of all images of elements of
>   $A$. Also, if
>   $f$ is a function from
>   $A$ to
>   $B$, we say
>   that
>   $f$ maps $A$
>   to
>   $B$.

---

Okay, by that definition we are all correct: Domain: $\mathbb Z$.

The codomain:$\mathbb Z$ and the range is {$1,2,5,....n^2 + 1$}$\subset \mathbb N$

I can't find the book's answer.

====

Found the book's answer.  It does indeed say "range equals $\mathbb Z^+ = \mathbb N \setminus \{0\}$".

And it is wrong.

These mistakes *do* happen.

But, rest assured, it is wrong.

Comment: The solutions are here: http://www.mediafire.com/file/c9c0puspavob7hj/soloution+Discrete+Mathematics+and+Its+Applications+%5B7th+Edition%5D+-+Kenneth+H.+Rosen+Student%27s+Solutions+Guidel.pdf

Comment: That only seems to be odd number problems.

Comment: It is a review question.

Comment: I found it.  And .... it is wrong....  It is stated that the answer is $\mathbb Z^+ = \mathbb N \setminus \{0\}$.  Which is ... wrong.  I can only assume they figured $f(n) = n^2 + 1 \ge 1$ so $\{f(n)|n \in \mathbb Z\} \subset \mathbb Z^+ $ so $\{f(n)|n \in \mathbb Z\} = \mathbb Z^+$. ... which is.... just wrong.  It is a *subset* of $Z^+$ but it isn't all of $Z^+$.